# How to update a foreign key with random values from the referenced table?

Tags: postgresql, subquery

In order to generate test data for a postgres database, I want to update a foreign key in a table, let's say 'users' with random values from the referenced table, let's say 'shift'.

How to do it?

I have tried this way:

```
UPDATE users
SET id_shift = (
SELECT shift.id_shift
FROM shift
ORDER BY random()
LIMIT 1
);
```

I expected to have some users in one shift and others in another. But the result is that all users end up with the same shift.

Comment: Yes, that is because there is no `WHERE` that assigns an `id_shift` to a given user(`user_id`?). As of now you are assigning all users the same `shift_id`. Is there some relationship between `users` and `shift`?

Comment: Thanks Adrian. Yes, id_shift is a foreign key in users that refers to shift. The answer from Laurenz Alber solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your subquery is not “correlated” (it does not reference a column in the outer query). So it is executed only once. You can fake it:

```
UPDATE users
SET id_shift = (SELECT shift.id_shift
                FROM shift
                /* pointless, but references the outer table */
                WHERE users.id IS NOT NULL
                ORDER BY random()
                LIMIT 1);
```

Then the subquery is executed for each row in `users`, and you'll get different rows.